# How to change class value in input with append use javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to change name of class in input, this is my HTML code:

```
<div id="c">
    <div class="aaa">
        <input id="b" name="aa" class="a" />
        <input id="b" name="aa" class="a nhay" />
        <input id="b" name="aa" class="a" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).on('keyup', '.nhay', function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        $(this).removeClass('a nhay');

        $('#c').append('<div class="aaa"><input id="b" name="aa" class="a"/><input id="b" name="aa" class="a nhay"/><input id="b" name="aa" class="a"/></div>');
    }
});
```

I want it like this when I press enter

out HTML:

```
<div id="c">
    <div class="aaa">
        <input id="b" name="aa" class="a" />
        <input id="b" name="aa" class="new name" />
        <input id="b" name="aa" class="a" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Note: classes should not have `space` in between..They will be treated as different classes..

Comment: the presented html markup is invalid - you should not use the same identifier for multiple elements

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to replace the elements, you can just add the new classes:

```
$(document).on('keyup', '.nhay',function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        $(this).removeClass('a nhay').addClass('new name');
    }
});
```

You could even shorten that to just a single call to `toggleClass()`:

```
$(this).toggleClass('a nhay new name');
```

Also note that having the same `id` attribute for multiple elements within the same document is invalid and you should change them to classes if you want to group those elements together.

Comment: thanks you. i did try and success. But why the cursor does not move through the input has been renamed

Comment: It's because it is still the same element, hence the focus remains. If you want to change the location of the cursor, use .focus() to put it on the required element

Comment: i do how  use .focus() to put it on the required element.

Comment: `$('#elementYouWant').focus()`

Comment: not. I mean . I want the cursor to move through each input in order from left to right when I press enter

Answer (score 0):

Note: Elements in the DOM should *not* share the same id tag. For example, you should not have 3 input elements all with the same id="b".

To change the class, you can use the .removeClass() followed by the .addClass() jQuery methods:

```
// select the input element with id=b
$("input#b").on('keyup', function(e) {
    // remove classes "a" and "nay", add classes "new" and "name"
    $(this).removeClass("a nhay").addClass("new name");
});
```